# Compute the Fourier transform of $f(x) = \exp(-x^2/2)$ while solving the ODE $F(x) = -x F(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f(x) = \exp(-x^2/2)$ and let $F(x) = f^\wedge = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \exp(-ixt) dt$ be the Fourier transform of $f$. It can be shown that $F$ satisfied the ODE

$$y'(x) = - x y(x)$$

(see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796007/show-that-the-fourier-transform-of-fx-exp-x2-2-satisfies-the-different)).

Furthermore, the general solution of the ODE is

$$y(x) = C \exp(-x^2/2)$$

for any constant $C$.

In my exercise, I am asked to show that $F(x) = \sqrt{2 \pi} \exp(-x^2/2)$. We were told to use the identity

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^2/2) dx = \sqrt{2\pi}$$.

I tried to write

$$C \exp(-x^2/2) = f^\wedge(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-t^2/2 - ixt) dt,$$

but the right term does not seem to converge. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: You must complete the square inside the exponential and then translate the variable of integration in order to apply the gaussian integral formula.

Comment: So $\exp(-t^2/2-ixt) = \exp(-x^2/2) \exp(-(t+ix)^2/2)$. But is it possible to set $u=t+ix$? I think, it is not, since $u$ is complex then and hence the interval of the integral does not make much sense.

Comment: @ANTLearner, you are right, that that change of variables is not happening inside the real numbers. But it turns out to be ok, thinking in terms of moving contours in contour integrals in complex variables. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the general solution, $y(x)=Ce^{-x^2/2}$,  to the ODE $y'(x)=-xy(x)$, the constant $C$ can be found as follows.

Recall that $y(x)$ is defined here as

$$y(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2/2}e^{-ixt}\,dt$$

So, we see that $C=y(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\,dt=\sqrt{2\pi}$.  Therefore, $C=\sqrt{2\pi}$ and we are done!